# State variable ERC721Token

Tags: solidity

```
contract Test {
  ERC721Token public tokenAddress;

  constructor(address _address) public {
    tokenAddress = ERC721Token(_address);
  }
}
```

In this example, I just tested `tokenAddress` returns the address of a ERC721Token contract. If it's just returning an address, how come the state variable `tokenAddress`'s type is `ERC721Token` and not `address`?

and the line here, 
`tokenAddress = ERC721Token(_address);`
What does `ERC721Token(_address)` mean? Does it mean it's searching a specific `ERC721Token` contract from the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract casting is only used for the compiler to know the functions available on the contract. Internally, you're right that tokenAddress is just an address, and `ERC721Token(_address)` isn't really doing anything other than allowing the compiler to know the functions.

Otherwise, the compiler would fail if you tried calling ERC721Token functions on a regular address.